# REST API and ETag on individual resources of a list

Tags: rest, http, etag

Considering I have a REST API exposing a repository of users :

- /users/ -> returns an array of UserModel
- /users/{Id} -> returns a UserModel

I needs to implement a client application that support offline mode (API not available) that will display the list of users and the detail of each user.

I am considering to synchronize in the client app the users this way :

1. Get the full list of users by calling a GET on /users/ and persist the list of users
2. Each time a user is accessing a user profile, if REST API available, check if the user has been updated by calling the REST API and update the user details if necessary
3. Display the user profile

I am considering using ETag (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_ETag) to implement this behavior.

My issue is that **I don't want my client application to get user details one by one by calling GET /users/{Id} but in a bulk by calling GET /users/ (with some paging if needed)**. If I do so, the client application will get a global ETAG of the list of users, but **not ETags of each user**. Thus it will not be able to verify individually if a user entity is up-to-date.

As a workaround, I am considering to add an ETAG field to the UserModel of the API. This way after calling GET /users/, the client app will be able to check if a specific user has been updated by calling GET /users/{Id} with the If-None-Match <User'sETagValue> header.

I know that the solution do no stick to he HTTP 1.1 standard, and that it adds a little complexity to the ETag generation.

However, I can't find any other post describing such a solution and I am wondering if it presents major issues ? And If there are more elegant solutions ?

Thanks for your help,

Edit : WebDav standard defines a "DAV:getetag" property that looks similar to my approach (http://www.webdav.org/specs/rfc4918.html#cache-control)

Answer (score 1):

The WebDAV spec is also the first thing that came to mind for me.

I don't see an issue with adding etags to the response of your collection. You might even define a collection in a more general way, so that the format is just a list of URIs, their responses and headers so your client can treat it as a list of resources that need to be written to a cache.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, in the meantime I had observed that Azure API also return etags as part of their model. Seams that the solution is rather common.